# Group by column and select range of each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, filtering

```
id refid    date1  date2        nextdate
5   10  2008-02-21  2009-02-21  004/2008
6   10  2009-02-09  2010-02-09  002/2009
7   10  2010-02-08  2011-02-08  001/2010
10  11  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  002/2007
11  11  2008-02-21  2009-02-21  001/2008
12  11  2009-02-09  2010-02-09  001/2009
13  11  2010-02-09  2011-02-09  002/2010
14  11  2011-07-19  2012-07-19  054/2011
15  11  2012-07-17  2013-07-17  066/2012
18  14  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  006/2007
25  16  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  004/2007
27  16  2009-02-10  2010-02-10  004/2009
28  16  2010-02-12  2011-02-12  005/2010
29  16  2011-07-26  2012-07-26  055/2011
30  16  2012-07-18  2013-07-18  067/2012
```

I have this datatable. I need to filter datatable by following contitions.
If  refid have more than 4 same values than I need first one and last 3. If I have 4 and less same refid valuses than do nothing. Result should be like this:

```
id   refid  date1   date2       nextdate
5   10  2008-02-21  2009-02-21  004/2008
6   10  2009-02-09  2010-02-09  002/2009
7   10  2010-02-08  2011-02-08  001/2010
10  11  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  002/2007
13  11  2010-02-09  2011-02-09  002/2010
14  11  2011-07-19  2012-07-19  054/2011
15  11  2012-07-17  2013-07-17  066/2012
18  14  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  006/2007
25  16  2007-02-15  2008-02-15  004/2007
28  16  2010-02-12  2011-02-12  005/2010
29  16  2011-07-26  2012-07-26  055/2011
30  16  2012-07-18  2013-07-18  067/2012
```

How to do that?

Comment: `Datatable` means the .NET in-memory `DataTable`? If so, what language are you using? If not, what rdbms are you using? Anyway, how do you want to order?

Comment: First datatable is from my query. I just want to modify my query to get wanted results. Conditions are : If refid have more than 4 same values than I need first one and last 3. If I have 4 and less same refid valuses than do nothing.

Comment: I use SLQ 2008 and for first datatable I use query
select id, refid, date1, date2, nextdate from MyTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT [id], [refid], [date1], [date2], [nextdate],
     RN_ASC = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(
           PARTITION BY refid
           ORDER BY id ASC),
      RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(
           PARTITION BY refid
           ORDER BY id DESC)
  FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT [id], [refid], [date1], [date2], [nextdate] 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN_ASC = 1 OR RN_DESC <= 3
ORDER BY [id]
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed6ee/5/0)</kbd>

[**Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)